# Quickblox ipv6 support

Tags: ios, ipv6, quickblox

We have an live app on App Store using quickblox ios sdk v2.1.1.

We are trying to upload a new version of the app. (Apple has rejected the latest build as quickblox login fails in ipv6 network)

But as per Apple's announcement of transitioning to IPv6-only network services in iOS 9. Starting June 1, 2016 all apps submitted to the App Store must support IPv6-only networking.

And, quickblox added the support of ipv6 in 2.7.2.1.

Is there a way of fixing ipv6 support without migrating to updated sdk?

Comment: Please, contact our [Support team](http://assist.quickblox.com/index.php?/Tickets/Submit) for help.

Answer (score 1):

please check - [iOS-QuickBlox-SDK-2.1.1-ipv6](http://sdk.quickblox.com/ios/iOS-QuickBlox-SDK-2.1.1-ipv6.zip)

Change log:

- QBChat with IPv6 support